# Trying to make a substitution using perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, substitution

I have this text:

```
rojo
```

I want to make a substitution and turn it into:

```
rojo77
```

So I'm trying this:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/(ojo)/$177/g" oven.txt
```

If I wanted to replace with text instead of with 77, I would have no problem, but being a number I get this as a result:

```
r
```

I mean, it matches `ojo`, but replacement isn't working, so everything matched just gets deleted. How can I use `$1` and use a number next to it?

Please help!

Comment: And if you indeed need to append to a string, then `$string .= '77';` does it

Answer (score 4):

As a starter: since you know in advance the exact string part that you are trying to match, you don't actually need the substitution variable:

```
s/ojo/ojo77/
```

But if you wanted to use the substitution variable, you could do:

```
s/(ojo)/${1}77/
```

As commented by [zdim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653379/zdim), this can also be expressed using [special assertion `\K`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns), which basically means *Keep the stuff left*:

```
s/ojo\K/77/
```

Comment: It worked! It worked! I feel such a relief. THANK YOU, MAN. THANK YOU.

Comment: starting with perl 5.10, you can also do `s/ojo/\K77/`

Comment: That's meant to be `s/ojo\K/77/`  (the `\K` is in the matching part, its purpose being to drop all previous matches, so they aren't "consumed" and thus don't need to be put back in the replacement part)

Comment: @zdim: thanks! I included the `\K` solution in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There a nice trick you can use with substitutions if you don't want to replace part of the pattern. The `\K` excludes from the replacement the part of pattern that comes before it:

```
perl -pi.bak -e "s/ojo\K/77/g" oven.txt
```

I write more about it in [Ignore part of a substitution’s match](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2012/10/ignore-part-of-a-substitutions-match/)

Besides that, remember how Perl figures out a variable name. It takes all the legal identifier characters after the sigil. Since `177` is a legal variable name (even though you don't have that many captures), that's the name you get. To set apart the variable name from the rest of the text, you can surround the variable name with braces (sigil still outside):

```
"r$177"   # variable named 177
"r${1}77" # variable 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way using `e` to concatenate the values in replacements.

```
s/(ojo)/$1.77/eg; # '.' dot will merge/concatenate the values from left and right
```

Thanks for pointing out champ [zdim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653379/zdim) in my box comments:

```
s/(ojo)/$1.q(77)/eg;
```

Evaluates the replacement as if it were a Perl statement, and uses its return value as the replacement text [`e`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_regular_expression.htm)

Comment: While this works as it stands since `77` is a number after all (and is then converted for concatenation), I'd suggest to use an explicit string literal when it need be concat-ed, so `$1.q(77)`

Comment: This works, but it's a slightly larger hammer than you need to interpolate a value.

Comment: @briandfoy: Accepted. Best and Simplified answers are provided by champs. And this is an optional.